# Borrowing an iPhone 4 - I've swapped the sim but can I access my email and iMessages without loosing the owner's?

Tags: iphone, sim

Can I access my mail and iMessages without wiping the iPhone first?  I want to return the phone to its pre-loan state when I'm done borrowing.

Comment: The SIM swap isn't even necessary.  You can do the things suggested in the existing 2 answers without swapping the SIM.  The SIM is connected to your phone number, not your internet identity or appleid.  You can also likely access your email in a normal web browser.

Comment: @Tyson Without doing a SIM swap, he can't receive messages sent to his phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this, however you should just back it up to the owners computer first (with iTunes or iCloud). Then wipe the phone and when you are done with it, the owner can restore all of his data.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive iMessages by signing out of it and signing back in with your Apple ID. Any existing messages will still be there, and you would only receive your messages from now going forward.

You could add your email account, but any existing email accounts would still be there.